# How to use babel to dynamically transpile package consumed from node_modules when running in node?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I'm writing a NodeJS app, we'll call it App.

App consumes a published module from another team that we'll call Model.

Model consumes a published module called Foo. Foo is published as an ES6 module.

When App tries to run in Node, it fails with a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export" because Foo is published as an ES6 module and Node doesn't support ES6 modules (without turning on some experimental features), is my understanding.

I know that there is a [babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs) to transform ES6 to CommonJS modules, but I'm not sure what is the right/best way to use it in this situation. Keep in mind that MY "App" does not directly consume Foo, it is only indirectly consumed because App consumes Model which consumes Foo.

- Is there some way to tell Node that whenever it tries to load the Foo module, it should run it through babel first, at runtime? Is this possible? It seems like this would be the least invasive solution.
- I know I can transpile Foo's JS statically as part of building App, but unless I transpile it into exactly the same location in node_modules, the code in Model that references Foo won't know where to find it, and changing the content of node_modules doesn't seem right.
- Should the publisher of Model transpile/republish Foo as a CommonJS module as part of publishing Model itself?

I don't know which of these is possible or if any of them are a good idea. Is there precedent/best practices for this type of issue?

Thanks!